# filter data using multiple conditions dynamodb

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb

How can I filter data using multiple conditions in dynamodb.

I want to filter a table by post_date and district using scan method.

```
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'post_date = :today_date',
    FilterExpression : 'post_date = :today_date and district = :district',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':today_date' : today_date,
        ':district' : district
    }
};

let queryExecute = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    dynamoDB.scan(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
            rej(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Success! scan method fetch data from dynamodb");
            res(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* filter on multiple attributes using the scan operation:

```
var params= {
    TableName: "YOUR TABLE NAME",
    FilterExpression : 'post_date = :today_date and district = :district',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':today_date' : today_date,
        ':district' : district
    }
  }
```

Your example includes a `KeyConditionExpression`, which is not supported for the `scan` operation.  If you know the primary key of the item you want, you should be using the `query` operation.

The `scan` operation is what you use when you want to search across all partitions in your table.  The `query` operation is what you use if you what to search within a specific partition.

Since you are trying to execute a `scan` operation you'll need to remove the `KeyConditionExpression`.