# How to filter by elements in an array in dynamoose

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamoose

I've **dynamoose** schema like below.

```
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
 
var City = dynamoose.model('City', { id: Number, name: String });
```

and City names data like **'City1', 'City2',...'City100'**

I'm trying to get the cities whose city names are `'City2', 'City8'` and i didn't find any solution

i tried like below

```
Model.scan({ name: { contains: 'City2' } }).exec();
```

How to add `City8` also

**Note**: `name` column doesn't have any index

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66371600/11070125

Comment: @SulemanElahi they've not used dynamoose

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using scan. I would use query as it's more performant and more.

The query can be something like:

```
CitiesModel.query("name").eq("City01").or().where("name").eq("City10").exec()
```

Regards!